# index signature assertion with generic types

Tags: typescript, generics, types, assertion

i'm building a custom event emitter that accepts a literal string type describing the possible events as a generic type to build an Event -> Callbacks map. of course i could use the builtin Map, but come on...
i wanted to use the [] notation to change the keys that were the events listed
I've started with something like this:

```
type FunctionDescriptor = {func: Function, args: any[]}
class EventEmitter<Events extends string> {
  [k in Events as string]?: FunctionDescriptor[]
  somemethods(event: Events) {
    this[event] = [...]
  }
}
```

thing is, first: this doesn't work
second: even if the [] signature worked, we would need to change the right hand side to accept all the types we would need in the class, defeating the whole purpose of type cheking.
for example, something like: 
`let myEventMap = new EventEmitter<MyEvents>(); myEventMap["AnyKey"] = "AnyStuff"`
would be possible, and that's not the behaviour i want. 
after some time tinkering i came up with this:

```
type FunctionDescriptor = {func: Function, args: any[]}

class EventMap<Events> {
  protected _: { [k in Events as string]?: FunctionDescriptor[] };
  // type asserted method call
  add(event: Events, callback: Function) {
    // example on how to access it
    this._[event].push(callback)
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to typescript, so I don't really know if this is a good pattern solution for my goal, but for me it looks like it fits my goals:

> a) can't assign anything from outside aside from the bultin functions; 
> b) when you emit or add events, all of them are type checked. 
> c) it's very easy to create your generic type matching some API responses for ex.

i was very surprised that this worked. I really can't figure what syntax is right inside the [] when you're defining it.

any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need to add `callback` to events array, you should type it as `FunctionDescriptor` because that's what you expect here.

In order to add smth to the array of events you need to make sure that `event` property exists in `this.prop`

Here is an example:

```js
type Fn = (...args: any) => any

type FunctionDescriptor = { func: Fn, args: any[] }

type Data<T extends string> = {
    [P in T]: FunctionDescriptor[]
}

const isEvent = <T extends string>(prop: Partial<Data<T>>, event: T): prop is Partial<Data<T>> & Record<T, FunctionDescriptor[]> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(prop, event)

class EventMap<Events extends string> {
    protected prop: Partial<Data<Events>> = {};
    add(event: Events, callback: FunctionDescriptor) {
        if (isEvent(this.prop, event)) {
            this.prop[event].push(callback)
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXFJnCAJRIB8JZAUHaJLAK5wDGwAlgPZwAiEfO2xcwwHtiRQA3lABmbdsXgAaEniK0QAbQC6UAL4Mm0fpmCYAPABUoEAB7AIcACb4o%20YKLi4ayGTooYKgdAAUoLgQbPRUlbj5BYVFxSX06Yzp2Pi9I-ABRADcXYGlbeycXd09vKL8UMGweMGIwnG5MABsrc0tbKip1CGK4YGIbcmJG5ryoNuwO7t7rGwGoADIoACUIbOxXW3UYeN4BIRExCWx9fyogkIB5ACMAK13gNGmJUzQAC0x8A8AO5wMJNSALEBodhdToNcFDEbAcgMdidAEeIolACymDAVixow8jmcbg8Xh8flk92CX3eEFcUGmLTm7S4XR6FmshOA%20DWAUMAG4aSRXK4UMMSsQefh1DDOp0nph2ABrOIcBJnZKXSSUQIhA2ReSoLgFJEoYC-U2fBH2JHkPUiw0hS3W5k6SWjPSfFj4X4oeWK5UqlHO4LGA3GQxAA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe), in my blog, you can find more information about typing events